# Dynamically update an object shared between two uiGrids AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have two uiGrids on a page each one actually relies on the same source of data, and a filter is used on one of the columns in each grid to decide which items should appear in which grid, the  idea is that if I want an item to appear in the other grid I just have to update a property on the object and it will jump across.

The issue I'm having is that when I update a property on an object in the data, I can see the change reflected in the data in the grid, but it doesn't jump across to the other grid - if however, I supply a fresh object it will jump across.

I have setup the following code (based on one of the uiGrid tutorials) on Plunker (http://plnkr.co/edit/duMg0OZaZm7p8uSpTK0q?p=preview) demonstrating the problem - the top grid should show the object if the object has the gender property as 'male', and it should move to the bottom grid if the gender is 'female', when using the update button you can see the gender change but stay in the current grid.  I've also tried using an external filter and manually updating that to see if it triggers a refresh but it didn't work.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ngTouch', 'ui.grid']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'uiGridConstants',
  function($scope, $http, uiGridConstants) {
    $scope.gridOptions = {
      enableFiltering: true,
      columnDefs: [
        // default
        {
          field: 'name'
        },
        // pre-populated search field
        {
          field: 'gender',
          filter: {
            term: 'male'
          }
        },
        // no filter input
        {
          field: 'company',
          enableFiltering: false,
          filter: {
            noTerm: true,
            condition: function(searchTerm, cellValue) {
              return cellValue.match(/a/);
            }
          }
        },
        // specifies one of the built-in conditions
        // and a placeholder for the input
        {
          field: 'email',
          filter: {
            condition: uiGridConstants.filter.ENDS_WITH,
            placeholder: 'ends with'
          }
        },
        // custom condition function
        {
          field: 'phone',
          filter: {
            condition: function(searchTerm, cellValue) {
              var strippedValue = (cellValue + '').replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
              return strippedValue.indexOf(searchTerm) >= 0;
            }
          }
        },
        // multiple filters
        {
          field: 'age',
          filters: [{
            condition: uiGridConstants.filter.GREATER_THAN,
            placeholder: 'greater than'
          }, {
            condition: uiGridConstants.filter.LESS_THAN,
            placeholder: 'less than'
          }]
        }
      ]
    };

    $scope.gridOptions2 = {
      enableFiltering: true,
      columnDefs: [
        // default
        {
          field: 'name'
        },
        // pre-populated search field
        {
          field: 'gender',
          filter: {
            term: 'female'
          }
        },
        // no filter input
        {
          field: 'company',
          enableFiltering: false,
          filter: {
            noTerm: true,
            condition: function(searchTerm, cellValue) {
              return cellValue.match(/a/);
            }
          }
        },
        // specifies one of the built-in conditions
        // and a placeholder for the input
        {
          field: 'email',
          filter: {
            condition: uiGridConstants.filter.ENDS_WITH,
            placeholder: 'ends with'
          }
        },
        // custom condition function
        {
          field: 'phone',
          filter: {
            condition: function(searchTerm, cellValue) {
              var strippedValue = (cellValue + '').replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
              return strippedValue.indexOf(searchTerm) >= 0;
            }
          }
        },
        // multiple filters
        {
          field: 'age',
          filters: [{
            condition: uiGridConstants.filter.GREATER_THAN,
            placeholder: 'greater than'
          }, {
            condition: uiGridConstants.filter.LESS_THAN,
            placeholder: 'less than'
          }]
        }
      ]
    };

    $scope.updateData = function() {
      if ($scope.myData.stuff[0].gender === 'male') {
        $scope.myData.stuff[0].gender = 'female';
      } else {
        $scope.myData.stuff[0].gender = 'male';
      }
    };



    $scope.replaceData = function() {
      if ($scope.myData.stuff[0].gender === 'male') {
        $scope.myData = {
          stuff: [{
            "id": 0,
            "guid": "de3db502-0a33-4e47-a0bb-35b6235503ca",
            "isActive": false,
            "balance": "$3,489.00",
            "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
            "age": 30,
            "name": "Sandoval Mclean",
            "gender": "female",
            "company": "Zolavo",
            "email": "sandovalmclean@zolavo.com",
            "phone": "+1 (902) 569-2412",
            "address": {
              "street": 317,
              "city": "Blairstown",
              "state": "Maine",
              "zip": 390
            },
            "about": "Fugiat velit laboris sit est. Amet eu consectetur reprehenderit proident irure non. Adipisicing mollit veniam enim veniam officia anim proident excepteur deserunt consectetur aliquip et irure. Elit aliquip laborum qui elit consectetur sit proident adipisicing.\r\n",
            "registered": "1991-02-21T23:02:31+06:00",
            "friends": [{
              "id": 0,
              "name": "Rosanne Barrett"
            }, {
              "id": 1,
              "name": "Nita Chase"
            }, {
              "id": 2,
              "name": "Briggs Stark"
            }]
          }]
        };
      } else {
        $scope.myData = {
          stuff: [{
            "id": 0,
            "guid": "de3db502-0a33-4e47-a0bb-35b6235503ca",
            "isActive": false,
            "balance": "$3,489.00",
            "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
            "age": 30,
            "name": "Sandoval Mclean",
            "gender": "male",
            "company": "Zolavo",
            "email": "sandovalmclean@zolavo.com",
            "phone": "+1 (902) 569-2412",
            "address": {
              "street": 317,
              "city": "Blairstown",
              "state": "Maine",
              "zip": 390
            },
            "about": "Fugiat velit laboris sit est. Amet eu consectetur reprehenderit proident irure non. Adipisicing mollit veniam enim veniam officia anim proident excepteur deserunt consectetur aliquip et irure. Elit aliquip laborum qui elit consectetur sit proident adipisicing.\r\n",
            "registered": "1991-02-21T23:02:31+06:00",
            "friends": [{
              "id": 0,
              "name": "Rosanne Barrett"
            }, {
              "id": 1,
              "name": "Nita Chase"
            }, {
              "id": 2,
              "name": "Briggs Stark"
            }]
          }]
        };
      }
      $scope.gridOptions.data = $scope.myData.stuff;
      $scope.gridOptions2.data = $scope.myData.stuff;
    };

    $scope.myData = {
      stuff: [{
        "id": 0,
        "guid": "de3db502-0a33-4e47-a0bb-35b6235503ca",
        "isActive": false,
        "balance": "$3,489.00",
        "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
        "age": 30,
        "name": "Sandoval Mclean",
        "gender": "male",
        "company": "Zolavo",
        "email": "sandovalmclean@zolavo.com",
        "phone": "+1 (902) 569-2412",
        "address": {
          "street": 317,
          "city": "Blairstown",
          "state": "Maine",
          "zip": 390
        },
        "about": "Fugiat velit laboris sit est. Amet eu consectetur reprehenderit proident irure non. Adipisicing mollit veniam enim veniam officia anim proident excepteur deserunt consectetur aliquip et irure. Elit aliquip laborum qui elit consectetur sit proident adipisicing.\r\n",
        "registered": "1991-02-21T23:02:31+06:00",
        "friends": [{
          "id": 0,
          "name": "Rosanne Barrett"
        }, {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Nita Chase"
        }, {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Briggs Stark"
        }]
      }]
    };

    $scope.gridOptions.data = $scope.myData.stuff;
    $scope.gridOptions2.data = $scope.myData.stuff;

  }
]);
```

Does anyone have a simple fix?  When this gets used, it will be with data retrieved from a server and hundreds (possibly thousands) of objects, so I don't really want to be creating new data every time to make things work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use notifyDataChange

[uiGrid docs](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/316_dynamic_data_changes)